# How can I find why the reason of this error message?

Tags: 8, entities

I get this warning when I edit nodes.

> Notice: Undefined index: id in template_preprocess_fieldset() (line 217 of core/includes/form.inc).

I don't have any field with that machine name, nor did I create any specific template or hook. I don't understand where this can be coming from.

How do I clear that up?

Comment: Which core version are you using?

Comment: It's not a field machine name. The function is trying to access `$element['#attributes']['id']`, which is not defined. We cannot say the reason, from here.

Comment: i am using 8.4 version